# JobsListItem - Display bug in job listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

In the right hand column the text "JobsListItem" is being displayed between ads.

[image: Screenshot of the error.]

Comment: You don't want to become a JobsListItem? I hear they are paid well ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what happens when Visual Studio freezes as you're typing and things get typed into the wrong place. And then you miss it when committing.

Build is going out to prod now, thanks for the heads up